# Flutter: How to Display Timer-Updating Widget List

Tags: list, flutter, dart, timer, widget

The goal of this section of my app is to display a brand new `historyTile()` every minute, with each tile having it's own respective time and date to when it was saved to the `historyList`.

I am not sure exactly how this sort of function might work, but this is what I have so far. It is divided into two dart files.

activityTab.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:indietools/pages/tabs/functions/historyTile.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class activityTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const activityTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<activityTab> createState() => _activityTabState();
}

class _activityTabState extends State<activityTab> {

  List<Widget> historyList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (Timer t) => historyList.add(historyTile())
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [historyList]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

historyTile.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class historyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const historyTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<historyTile> createState() => _historyTileState();
}

class _historyTileState extends State<historyTile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final now = DateTime.now();
          String tileTime = DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm().format(now);
            return ListTile(

                leading: Icon(Icons.backup_outlined),
                title: Text('Synced   my_script.pdf   with the cloud.'),
                subtitle: Text('${tileTime}'),
                tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
            );
          }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: First of instead of adding a widget to the list, try adding a data model to the list and just update the state of list view afterwards.

Comment: create a data model which have your required variables and then create a list of that model and use that instead of Widgets model.
If you need more help, click on my profile and we can do something

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste it onto [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) to play with it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late Timer _timer;
  List<Widget> history = [];
  int _counter = 0;

  void _updateHistory(Timer timer) {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      history.add(ListTile(title: Text(_counter.toString())));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), _updateHistory);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: history,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _counter = 0;
            history.clear();
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Clear all',
        child: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```